# To be reminded of the old days

Tags: knowledge, pattern, lateral-thinking

*I recently was in a hotel in a small community somewhere near a capital of a certain country (I don't want to say exactly where, I'll let you figure that out on your own) which I was very fond of (had good knowledge related to it). It was very cheap to stay there so I stayed there for a week from Monday early morning to the next Monday early morning. They were a bit fanatic I heard from the locals. They told me they wanted to be reminded of the old days so they had this bell ring every day for a certain number of times at different times of the day to remind them of that. But I didn't get any more information than that...*

*...On Monday I heard the bell ring nine times at 9 in the morning. On Tuesday fourteen times at 10 in the evening. On Wednesday twenty-two times at midnight. On Thursday nine times at noon. On Friday three times at 3 in the morning. By now I could see a pattern. It all made sense. I said to myself "aha!, I know exactly how many times and when the bell will ring on Saturday and Sunday". And of course, after the weekend, I was exactly right on both days.*

---

**Near which capital city was I staying in? How many times and *exactly* when did the bell ring on Saturday and Sunday?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were staying near:

> **Rome**, in Italy.

On Saturday, the bell rang:

> 20 times at 4am.

And on Sunday it rang:

> 1 time at 1pm.

There are two patterns at play here. Firstly, the number of chimes:

> In weekday order, the number of times the bell rings is 9 (Mon), 14 (Tue), 22 (Wed), 9 (Thu), 3 (Fri). If we convert these numbers to letters via A1Z26 we get I, N, V, I and C. These are the first five letters of the Latin word **INVICTA**, part of the phrase '[*Roma invicta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma_invicta)', an expression meaning 'unconquered Rome' and an inspirational motto used until the fall of the Roman Empire in 476AD (Source: Wikipedia). These are the good 'old days' that the locals are so fond of!
>
>  In order to complete the word 'INVICTA' the bell must ring 20 times (for a 'T') on Saturday, and just once (for an 'A') on Sunday.

Secondly, the time of day:

> Expressing these as 24-hour clock times (with a bit of license for midnight), those that we already know are 09:00 (Mon), 22:00 (Tue), 24:00 (Wed), 12:00 (Thu) and 03:00 (Fri). Converting these hours to letters via A1Z26, we get the sequence I, V, X, L, C - these are the **[Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)** in order of increasing value! The two remaining are D and M, which would translate to times 04:00 and 13:00, i.e. 4 in the morning and 1 in the afternoon.

Comment: Quick! You got everything right, well done!